# Image quality lost after resizing with css

Tags: css

I am trying to resize an image with css but the image is loosing quality. Can I resize with keeping the quality the same? If I remove the width and height from the image styling the image is perfect.I am attaching the image after the width and height is set.

```
<div flex="70" style="border:thin solid lightgray;">                                           
    <img style="display:block; width: 500px; height: auto;" ng-src="{{$ctrl.zoomedImage}}" />                                            
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WpXJ.png)

Comment: You can try to influence how your browser scales the image, using the [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) property. If that is not enough - then you will have to use a different source image size to begin with.

Comment: have you try object-fit:contain ? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if your example is correct?
**Based on your Example:**

The SHOWN(!) image (your url!) itself is in an awfuly bad quality and to be honest far below the resolution you need for modern even mobile screens ... it does not matter if you resize such a bad image ... the quality is still the same bad one.

1. First step is to prepare the image in a good quality and than have a look if it really fits your requirements.
2. And if you want to optimize that you may like to get some information about how to prepare and present images in web here is a good article: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images

*Additonal Notice: If you really want to have best view on different devices at the end you may like to have a special look to the `srcset`-attribute explained in the article.*